# How Can I get days of an specific Week in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, date, week-number, datetime-generation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculating days of week given a week number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186431/calculating-days-of-week-given-a-week-number)

In PHP you can get the number of week with 'date('W');' and it will return *ISO-8601 week number of year*

Now how I can get the days of an specific week and the month(s) ?

Update:
For example I know 'Monday the 12th week of 2011' and want to get '31st March'

Comment: do you mean something like input:date (1/1/2011) output: sunday ?

Comment: Do you have year information?

Comment: @ircmaxell, that question didn't asked on an specific language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For days in a month you can use [cal_days_in_month](http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php) and for days in a specified week you can check out the following question: [Calculating days of week given a week number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186431/calculating-days-of-week-given-a-week-number)

Comment: Sweet! I will have a look at that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$start = strtotime('this Sunday');
$finish = strtotime('this Saturday');

$days = array();

while ($start <= $finish) {
   $days[] = date('d-m', $start);
   $start += strtotime('+1 day', 0);
}

var_dump($days);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/BxjPFgkk).

#### Output

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "24-04"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "25-04"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "26-04"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "27-04"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "28-04"
  [5]=>
  string(5) "29-04"
  [6]=>
  string(5) "30-04"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs at  http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

I think you want `date('d')` and `date('F')`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that is for today not an specific day of a specific week.

Comment: True, but you can just pass in your desired date as the second param, like @fingerman has above.  PHP's date functions are very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I got somthing for you:

```
// Prints: July 1, 2000 is on a Saturday
echo "July 1, 2000 is on a " . date("l", mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2000));
```

you can also do:

```
// out: July 1,2000 is on the 7th day
echo "July 1, 2000 is on the " . date("N", mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2000)) ."th day";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php