# Get data in SELECT MySQL by a day in field type timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want select rows in where a day in specific i.e. "Monday", but my type column is a timestamp "AAAA-MM-DD HH:MM:SS". I've searched but I don't how to select this.

My table is this, and the field is forex_pair_price_time (timestamp):

```
mysql> describe forex_pair_price;
+-------------------------+----------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field                   | Type           | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-------------------------+----------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
...
| forex_pair_price_time   | timestamp      | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
...
+-------------------------+----------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: can you add a sample data and what you are trying to select?

Comment: you can use SUBSTR function to get the year month and day and use code something like this to convert it to the days of the week, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186431/calculating-days-of-week-given-a-week-number

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-weekday

Use WEEKDAY(date).

The WEEKDAY function returns a weekday index for a date i.e., 0 for Monday, 1 for Tuesday, … 6 for Sunday.

```
Select * from forex_pair_price 
where weekday(forex_pair_price_time)=0
```

Or

```
Dayname(forex_pair_price_time)='Monday'
```

I think it is saver to use `weekday` because it is an compare to an integer instead of string. This is saver against problems with typos in String.

Answer (score 0):

To find all records where the forex timestamp happen to land on Monday, we can try using `DAYNAME`:

```
SELECT *
FROM forex_pair_price
WHERE DAYNAME(forex_pair_price_time) = 'Monday';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT forex_pair_price_time,
CASE 
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(orex_pair_price_time) = 1 THEN "Sunday"
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(orex_pair_price_time) = 2 THEN "Monday"
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(orex_pair_price_time) = 3 THEN "Tuesday"
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(orex_pair_price_time) = 4 THEN "Wednesday"
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(orex_pair_price_time) = 5 THEN "Thursday"
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(orex_pair_price_time) = 6 THEN "Friday"
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(orex_pair_price_time) = 7 THEN "Saturday"
  END Weekday
 FROM forex_pair_price
```